# Postman Cannot Send A Request With Bearer Token

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, postman

I enter the token and pick the bearer token as the token type. Everything looks good but the request does not reach my route handler and I get "Unable to verify the first certificate" warning with an empty response body and 200Ok.

I already turned off the SSL thing but I still get that warning. It looks like there's no other case like that on the Internet.

Do you know what's happening?

I'm trying to do an authorized post operation on my RESTful API and I expect to get a json. When I try to do that without token it gives me unauthorized response which is what I want. But when I want to do the operation with a token the thing above happens.

Comment: Do you get the same message if you choose "No Auth" and enter the Authorization header manually on the Headers tab?

Authorization: Bearer eyJ0

Comment: Try to calling the API with the Bearer token from client site (such as using JQuery Ajax to call the API), whether request success or not? After researching online, it seems that this issue might be related to the Postman, you could try to turn off the certificate verification, and upgrade the Postman to the latest version. Besides, from [this thread](https://community.postman.com/t/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate/10325), it seems that is using access token, you could try to add a new Access token.

Comment: Yeah the same thing happens @ScottMcNeany

Comment: So I read this one too and there's now CA certificates option instead of getting new access token. And I really could not figure out how to get to that cert since it's sort of complicated. @ZhiLv